# After update Visual Studio raises an error for Android

Tags: c#, android, maui

I have just updated Visual Studio to the latest Version 17.9.3. Now, I'm working on a `NET8` `MAUI` project. When I try to build the package in `Release` for `Android`, I get this error:

> 1>C:\Projects\ERDevOps\LIUApp\LanguageInUse\Platforms\Android\AndroidManifest.xml
> : error APT2260: resource mipmap/appicon (aka
> com.languageinuse.app:mipmap/appicon) not found.
> 1>C:\Projects\ERDevOps\LIUApp\LanguageInUse\Platforms\Android\AndroidManifest.xml
> : error APT2260:
> 1>C:\Projects\ERDevOps\LIUApp\LanguageInUse\Platforms\Android\AndroidManifest.xml
> : error APT2260: This error is likely caused by an issue with the
> AndroidManifest.xml file or an Android manifest generation attribute
> in a source code file.
> 1>C:\Projects\ERDevOps\LIUApp\LanguageInUse\Platforms\Android\AndroidManifest.xml
> : error APT2260: resource drawable/liulogo (aka
> com.languageinuse.app:drawable/liulogo) not found.
> 1>C:\Projects\ERDevOps\LIUApp\LanguageInUse\Platforms\Android\AndroidManifest.xml
> : error APT2260:
> 1>C:\Projects\ERDevOps\LIUApp\LanguageInUse\Platforms\Android\AndroidManifest.xml
> : error APT2260: This error is likely caused by an issue with the
> AndroidManifest.xml file or an Android manifest generation attribute
> in a source code file. 1>C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\34.0.52\tools\Xamarin.Android.Aapt2.targets(214,3):
> error APT2067: failed processing manifest. 1>C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\34.0.52\tools\Xamarin.Android.Aapt2.targets(214,3):
> error APT2067: 1>C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\34.0.52\tools\Xamarin.Android.Aapt2.targets(214,3):
> error : Could not find file
> 'C:\Projects\ERDevOps\LIUApp\LanguageInUse\obj\Release\net8.0-android\android\manifest\aapt_rules.txt'.
> 1>C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\34.0.52\tools\Xamarin.Android.Aapt2.targets(214,3):
> error :    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String
> maybeFullPath) 1>C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\34.0.52\tools\Xamarin.Android.Aapt2.targets(214,3):
> error :    at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode,
> FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share,
> Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs,
> String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean
> checkHost) 1>C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\34.0.52\tools\Xamarin.Android.Aapt2.targets(214,3):
> error :    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode,
> FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions
> options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath,
> Boolean checkHost) 1>C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\34.0.52\tools\Xamarin.Android.Aapt2.targets(214,3):
> error :    at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path, Encoding
> encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize,
> Boolean checkHost) 1>C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\34.0.52\tools\Xamarin.Android.Aapt2.targets(214,3):
> error :    at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path, Encoding
> encoding) 1>C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\34.0.52\tools\Xamarin.Android.Aapt2.targets(214,3):
> error :    at System.IO.File.ReadLines(String path) 1>C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\34.0.52\tools\Xamarin.Android.Aapt2.targets(214,3):
> error :    at
> Xamarin.Android.Tasks.Aapt2Link.d__117.MoveNext()

[image]

Just before updating Visual Studio, the solution was build and the deployment was working.

Comment: Did you use any NuGet package?

Comment: I have a lot of NuGet packages. I could build the project until just before the Visual Studio upgrade.

Comment: Have you tried a clean rebuild? I recently got a similar message just after a pull of some changes.